# Code Organization: How to best group functions, classes, etc

Tags: c#, code-organization

**Scenario:** You have a reasonably sized project with some forms, classes, etc.

**Question:** How would you group your functions? Would you put the functions common to all the forms into one separate class or a number of classes depending on function? What about your database calls. Would you have one class that contained all your database functions? Or would your create a utility class that would handle the calls?

**Reason:** I'm looking for some direction on how to best "group" functions. For instance I can see that having all the database functions in one class would make it easier to change/debug later, but is that necessary? I'm partial to the utility that handles all the connections for you and returns the formatted result but the SQL code does end up all over the place.

**End Note:** I know there are a lot of questions but as I said I'm looking for direction, you don't have to take every answer and answer it to a T but some coding guidelines or some coding wisdom from past experiences would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks,

Comment: Does it really make sense to group all your database functions in the same class? What happens if you create another instance of that class (assuming not a singleton)? Does it make sense to do that? What happens if you later want to reuse parts of that class? Splitting into DB Utils (for connections, sessions)  and another class(es) for DML might make sense. Hard to say without know more about your project.

Comment: Well all the functions are static functions. I asked this because I'm currently working on a project(I received halfway through) that has a DatabaseFunctions class and am contemplating reworking it to get rid of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [3-Tier Architecture](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article71.aspx). But if you're looking for something more in depth, there are many great books on the subject of Application Architecture. You could try [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420).